# Cross-Referencing Tables in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I am having difficulty finding the right command to create a new table that contains the stats of specific players based on the names of players that are in a separate table I made. For example, I have a table that contains the names of multiple NBA players in the table `Daddy_Gang` and I want to pull their stats from the stats table into a new table that displays the stats of the players from `Daddy_Gang`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickly, don't post photos of your datasets, code, errors, etc. Post the actual dataset (or a small sample), the actual code, etc. No one really wants to manufacture a dataset and/or your code.

But, once you get your list you can use `.isin()`.

Also double check how you are creating that list. You are creating a list of lists.
So change that line to:

`g = list(Daddy_Gang.values)`

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

stats = pd.DataFrame([
        ['Aaron Gordon', 3, 45],
        ['Coby White', 5, 33],
        ['Zach LaVine', 7, 22],
        ['apad13', 0, 0]],
        columns = ['Player', 'G', 'PTS'])

g = ['Coby White', 'Zach LaVine']


g = list(stats['Player'].values)

filtered_df = stats[stats['Player'].isin(g)]
```

**Output:**

```
print (filtered_df)
        Player  G  PTS
1   Coby White  5   33
2  Zach LaVine  7   22
```